# запись активных табов в бд, с последющим выводом

Tags: php, javascript

Задача такого рода - имеется выпадающий список, в котором записаны названия табов. Нужно, чтобы при клике по определённому табу в выпадающем списке, он добавлялся в активные табы, а при клике по значку удаления, удалялся. При чём при добавлении, нужно чтобы название таба удалялось из выпадающего списка, и добавлялось, при его деактивации. Но, самая сложная часть - это, нужно записать в базу данных то, какие табы были активированы, чтобы для всех пользователей выводились именно те, которые были выбраны. Выпадающий список и табы реализованы с помощью bootsrap 3. Как можно реализовать данную задачу?

```
<div class="dropdown">
          <p class="cursor_pointer" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
              Информационные базы
              <b class="caret"></b>
          </p>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu infobase_drop">
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="gib">База ГИБ</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="country">База стран</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="currenci">База валют</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="package">База пакетов</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="activitidirection">Направление деят-ти</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="branch">Отрасль</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="industrialdirection">Промышленное направление</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="measuri">Ед. Измерения</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="fo">Федеральный округ</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="region">Регион</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="logistic">Логистика</li>
              <li class="hover_li" data-metod="quality">Качество</li>
          </ul>
        </div>





<div class="row content-nav-tabs">
  <div class="col-xs-12">    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs ul__for_tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#baseGIB" aria-controls="baseGIB" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">База ГИБ</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a id="primeCountry" href="#baseWin2" aria-controls="baseWin2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchCountry">База стран</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a id="primeCurrencies" href="#baseWin3" aria-controls="baseWin3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name ="searchCurrenci">База валют</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin4" aria-controls="baseWin4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchPackage">База пакетов</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin5" aria-controls="baseWin5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchActivitiDirection">Направление деят-ти</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin6" aria-controls="baseWin6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchMonitoringBranch">Отрасль</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin7" aria-controls="baseWin7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchIndustrialDirection">Промышленное направление</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin8" aria-controls="baseWin." role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchMeasuri">Ед. Измерения</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin9" aria-controls="baseWin9" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchFo">Федеральный округ</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin10" aria-controls="baseWin10" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchRegion">Регион</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin11" aria-controls="baseWin11" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchLogistic">Логистика</a><button></button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#baseWin12" aria-controls="baseWin12" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchQualityMeasure">Качество</a><button></button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь - табы это такой элемент интерфейса, где активным может быть только 1 таб (если вы имели в виду именно табы). Получается в выпадающем списке, при выборе одного из табов, он активируется (и удаляется из списка) а затем при выборе другого он возвращается в список? Или как? Если так - то в базу должен быть записан только 1 активный в данный момент таб? Или все которые когда-либо были активированы пользователем? Или вы используете табы просто в качестве списка активных/не активных элементов ?

Comment: наверное немного не корректно описал ситуацию.. есть список табов, нужно, чтоб при клике на конкретный, он выводился на экран и его можно было кликнуть(сделать активным), и при клике на остальные, они также выводились на экран(но становились активными лишь при клике по какому-то конкретному уже на самом экране), а при нажатии на кнопку "удалить" удалялись с экрана и снова выводились в выпадающий список

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему вот таким образом(ниже). А данные в бд передаю в json формате.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab_add', function() {
      var post = {};
      post.ajaxRequest = true;
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'country') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="country"><a id="primeCountry" href="#baseWin2" aria-controls="baseWin2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchCountry">База стран</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="country"></button></li>');
        post.country = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'currenci') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="currenci"><a id="primeCurrencies" href="#baseWin3" aria-controls="baseWin3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name ="searchCurrenci">База валют</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="currenci"></button></li>');
        post.currenci = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'package') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="package"><a href="#baseWin4" aria-controls="baseWin4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchPackage">База пакетов</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="package"></button></li>');
        post.package = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'activitidirection') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="activitidirection"><a href="#baseWin5" aria-controls="baseWin5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchActivitiDirection">Направление деят-ти</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="activitidirection"></button></li>');
        post.activitidirection = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'branch') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="branch"><a href="#baseWin6" aria-controls="baseWin6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchMonitoringBranch">Отрасль</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="branch"></button></li>');
        post.branch = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'industrialdirection') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="industrialdirection"><a href="#baseWin7" aria-controls="baseWin7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchIndustrialDirection">Промышленное направление</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="industrialdirection"></button></li>');
        post.industrialdirection = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'measuri') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="measuri"><a href="#baseWin8" aria-controls="baseWin8" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchMeasuri">Ед. Измерения</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="measuri"></button></li>');
        post.measuri = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'fo') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="fo"><a href="#baseWin9" aria-controls="baseWin9" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchFo">Федеральный округ</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="fo"></button></li>');
        post.fo = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'region') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="region"><a href="#baseWin10" aria-controls="baseWin10" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchRegion">Регион</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="region"></button></li>');
        post.region = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'logistic') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="logistic"><a href="#baseWin11" aria-controls="baseWin11" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchLogistic">Логистика</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="logistic"></button></li>');
        post.logistic = 1;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'quality') {
        $('ul.ul__for_tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="style_of_tabs" id="quality"><a href="#baseWin12" aria-controls="baseWin12" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-name="searchQualityMeasure">Качество</a><button class="delite_tabs" data-metod="quality"></button></li>');
        post.quality = 1;
      }
      $(this).remove();
      console.log(post);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delite_tabs', function() {
      var post = {};
      post.ajaxRequest = true;
      $(this).parents('li').remove();
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'country') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="country">База стран</li>');
        post.country = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'currenci') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="currenci">База валют</li>');
        post.currenci = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'package') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="package">База пакетов</li>');
        post.package = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'activitidirection') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="activitidirection">Направление деят-ти</li>');
        post.activitidirection = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'branch') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="branch">Отрасль</li>');
        post.branch = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'industrialdirection') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="industrialdirection">Промышленное направление</li>');
        post.industrialdirection = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'measuri') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="measuri">Ед. Измерения</li>');
        post.measuri = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'fo') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="fo">Федеральный округ</li>');
        post.fo = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'region') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="region">Регион</li>');
        post.region = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'logistic') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="logistic">Логистика</li>');
        post.logistic = 0;
      }
      if ($(this).data('metod') == 'quality') {
        $('ul.infobase_drop').append('<li class="hover_li tab_add" data-metod="quality">Качество</li>');
        post.quality = 0;
      }
      // row.find('.tab_add').text(post.r_name);
      console.log(post);
    });
```